# Deploy WAR to ROOT folder using MSDeploy ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy, azure-rm-template

I am using ARM Template to create a Azure App Service with Tomcat container and Deploy application as .war file. Here is my template.json with MSDeploy extension

```
{
     "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
     "name": "MSDeploy",
     "type": "Extensions",
     "dependsOn": [
      "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('appservice_name'))]",
       "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('appservice_name'), '/config/web')]"
     ],
     "properties": {
       "packageUri": "<StorageUrl>/Application.war"
     }
  }
```

It was working fine and deploying my war file to wwwroot folder but I need to deploy into wwwroot/ROOT folder.

Is there any way to specify deployment path in MSDeploy ARM Template?

Comment: You could try to go to App Setting change the PHYSICAL PATh to site\wwwroot\root. Or add the value CM_TARGET_PATH  with the D:\home\site\wwwroot\root. And this way in the [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-folder-for-a-node-php-or-aspnet-site), I tried, but failed.

Comment: Hey @GeorgeChen I can able to deploy war within ROOT folder if I change my Physical path but I'm getting some memory releated error.